# how to install blackarch tools in debian based distro?

Tags: kali-linux, utilities, debian

Black Arch have wide ranges of tools, we can install all those tools in arch based linux with strap.sh. Offsec repo does not have this much tools. Please share some solution to install those tools with automation to debian based distro.
how to install blackarch tool in debian based distro?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of [black arch tools](https://blackarch.org/tools.html), You need to check for the package availability with `apt` to install it from Kali repositories, if the package isn't available you should build it from source. E,g:

```
# apt search 0d1n 
* Running: apt-cache search 0d1n

# apt search 0trace
* Running: apt-cache search 0trace
0trace - traceroute tool that can run within an existing TCP connection
0trace-dbgsym - debug symbols for 0trace
```

`0d1n` should be built from source but `0trace` can be installed through `apt`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so are you saying the only way is to use the repo and check 1 at a time?
that really sounds time consuming. check apt, find source, compile & install.
Isn't there a better way?